# how to make a button look like a hyperlink aspx.net

Tags: asp.net, button

I would like to use a button (that doe's more than just links) appear as hyperlink in aspx.net. meaning the button wont have the white background it normally has, and simply look like a highlighted text, like a link.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Give your button a `CssClass`

```
<asp:Button ID="button" Text="Button" CssClass="button" />
```

Then apply css for your button:

```
.button {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You want an asp:LinkButtton control

W3 Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_linkbutton.asp

MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.80).aspx